# fractions turning to dates in sheets

Tags: csv, date, parsing, google-apps-script, fractions

I have data with values 5/8 and 3/4 that are provided in .csv file.

Example:

Raw CSV data:
[Cat, 1, 5/8], [Dog, 2, 5/8], [Tiger, 3, 5/8]

I take the csv and parse using:

```
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text, ',');    
ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

values that stored as 5/8 and 3/4 are being changed to dates, 5/8/2021

In sheets:

[Cat, 1, 5/8/2021], [Dog, 2, 5/8/2021], [Tiger, 3, 5/8/2021]

- is there a way to have 5/8 remain as a string and not treated as a number/date?

Comment: Try changing the numberFormat. Plaintext seems to work

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue but I failed to do so. I created a csv file based on your raw data. `Logger.log(text) => [Cat, 1, 5/8], [Dog, 2, 5/8], [Tiger, 3, 5/8]` while `Logger.log(csv) =>  [[[Cat,, 1,, 5/8],, [Dog,, 2,, 5/8],, [Tiger,, 3,, 5/8]]]`. I did not arrive to this sheet values `[Cat, 1, 5/8/2021], [Dog, 2, 5/8/2021], [Tiger, 3, 5/8/2021]`. Can you share a sample sheet and verify the raw csv data

Comment: try using this data     https://fractiondata22.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_data_20210413.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format of your range before setting its value.

### Sample Code:

```
  var url = 'https://fractiondata22.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_data_20210413.txt';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text, ','); 
  
  var range = ss.getRange(1,1,csv.length,csv[0].length);
  range.setNumberFormat("@");
  range.setValues(csv);
```

### What it does?

- Select the range based on the converted csv file data
- Change the format of the range using [Range.setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat). Use `@` as [number format token](http://Number%20format%20tokens)

> @
>
> Inserts the raw text for the cell, if the cell has text input. Not compatible with any of the other special characters and won’t display for numeric values (which are displayed as general format).

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! i didn't realize the setNumberFormat could be used in this way.

Comment: question on this, i noticed as a test when i entered a formula to test this, 'ISDATE(E13)' = TRUE and 'ISDATE(E14)=FALSE' , and when i enter ISTEXT, all values are TRUE. from what i can see, '5/8' is still a stored as a date and text, and '2' is stored only as text. is there a way to make ALL values always JUST text and not also a date?

Comment: Column E is already in plain text. If you want to verify, select column E or cell E13, go to Format -> Number (Plain Text should be checked). Though ISDATE() seems to consider a fraction as date.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your import:

```
ss.setNumberFormat("@");//plaintext
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text, ',');    
ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

You want to tell the cells that they are text before the csv tries to insert itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `getText()` call to the code.

For example:

```
var text_string = text.getText()
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text_string, ',');    
ss.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#gettext) for `getText()`

Comment: im using   text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); and get an error here: var text_string = text.getText()

Comment: Could you post a version of the spreadsheet you are using without any sensitive data?

Comment: I use: var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL).getContentText() where var URL =    "https://fractiondata22.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_data_20210413.txt"